# How to remove Grey box from Picker Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using `flutter_picker: ^2.0.0` plugin. And could not find option to remove grey box from Picker.

Here is my code :-

```
Picker(
      itemExtent: 50,
      magnification: 1.4,
      hideHeader: true,
      adapter: _picAdapterLB,
      selecteds: [_selectedWeightLb],
      height: 200,
      textStyle: MyTextStyle.pickerItem,
      selectedTextStyle: MyTextStyle.pickerSelectedItem,
      onSelect: (Picker picker, int index, List<int> tmp) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedWeight = picker.adapter.toString();
          _selectedWeightUnit = AppStrings.WEIGHT_LB;
        });
      },
    ).makePicker();
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify source code `Picker.dart` line `497`
and add `selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(background: Colors.transparent,),` 
https://github.com/yangyxd/flutter_picker/blob/00833be40cf63e11bcf9f534f1d3a7e9ed19f030/lib/Picker.dart#L497
code snippet

```
var _view = CupertinoPicker.builder(
              selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(background: Colors.transparent,),
```

Default `background` of `CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay` is `CupertinoColors.tertiarySystemFill`

```
class CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay extends StatelessWidget {

  /// Creates an iOS 14 style selection overlay that highlights the magnified
  /// area (or the currently selected item, depending on how you described it
  /// elsewhere) of a [CupertinoPicker].
  ///
  /// The [background] argument default value is [CupertinoColors.tertiarySystemFill].
```

working demo after modify source code

[image]

Comment: selectionOverlay is CupertinoPicker's argument now, just set it value no need change source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CupertinoPicker's [selectionOverlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker/selectionOverlay.html) property to modify the overlay

```
selectionOverlay
```

To remove the overlay just use (as @chunhunghan said):

```dart
selectionOverlay: const CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(background: Colors.transparent)
```

or

```dart
selectionOverlay: null
```